# How to fix the "Role "john" does not exist" when deploying PostgreSQL using Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm deploying a PostgreSQL service using Docker Compose, and I'm encountering an issue where the PostgreSQL role does not seem to exist, leading to authentication failures. Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
2023-12-30 13:29:28 2023-12-30 16:29:28.298 UTC [35] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "john"
2023-12-30 13:29:28 2023-12-30 16:29:28.298 UTC [35] DETAIL:  Role "john" does not exist.
2023-12-30 13:29:28     Connection matched file "/data/postgres/pg_hba.conf" line 140: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

I initiate the containers using the `docker compose up -d` command. Below is the relevant portion of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres-inventory:
    container_name: postgres-inventory
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: inventory-service
      POSTGRES_USER: john
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-inventory:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

What I've tried so far:

- Checking Environment Variables: I've verified that the environment variables for POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD are correctly set in the Docker Compose file.
- Volume Persistence: Considered that persistent volumes might be retaining old data, so I tried removing and recreating the volumes.
- Access Control Configuration: Examined the pg_hba.conf file to ensure it doesn't have any restrictive rules that might be causing the issue.

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

(I also tried to add the IP of containers)

My `data.sql` file:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'inventory-service';
```

My `application-docker.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.username=john
spring.datasource.password=secret
```

Is there a step in the PostgreSQL initialization that I might be missing which is essential for role creation?

EDIT: Just tried to run `netstat -ano | findstr :5432`, kill the processes and restart my host machine, but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "and recreating the volumes"?  Once you remove it, `docker up` should create it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the `docker-compose.yml` from the [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), and it worked.

I tried to make my yml file as similar as possible to the one in the official documentation.

```
  postgres-inventory:
    container_name: postgres-inventory
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: inventory-service
      POSTGRES_USER: john
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-inventory:/data/postgres
```